# send public key to host app in java card

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, javacard, key-pair

I am new to java card applet development.i want to create application which send me to public key for the future authentication.for the movement i used RSA algorithm for the create public key and private key.

```
keys = new KeyPair(KeyPair.ALG_RSA_CRT, KeyBuilder.LENGTH_RSA_2048);
        keys.genKeyPair();
        rsa_publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keys.getPublic();
```

now i want to send the public key to my host application.i found some way using modulus and exponent send the public key to host application.but i don't know how to implement that one.can some one please help me to implement the send public key to host application..
Thanks 
SSV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have the RSAPublicKey instance it is easy. There you have to methods for getting the modulus and the exponent. Both get-methods copy the requested value into a byte array you can return in an result APDU.

Note that for a common JavaCard without extended length APDUs a 2048 bit RSA key is to large to return it in one response APDU. Depending on the available bytes in the response APDU you may even have to split modulus and exponent into 2 or more parts for returning them to the host.

Comment: +1 although the maximum size of 256 bytes should be enough to send even the modulus in one go (unless the buffer size is too small or when a secure channel is being used). Actually, you have one bit to spare :P

Comment: Thanks.Owlsted and Robert.i complete using getModulus and getExponent.i will realy helpfull your comments.for the movement i got 256 bytes public key.i have another problem.this is the question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481157/genarate-key-token-using-mac-hash-funtion-in-java-card